# /dev/i2c is not showing Raspberry Pi4 running on Android

Tags: linux, android-source, raspberry-pi4

I am using AOSP android 11 in the RPi4. I have enabled the i2c in config.txt using the param `dtparam=i2c_arm=on`.

The i2c is showing in the `/sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-1` but `/dev/i2c` is not listing in the dev folder.

I want to access the APDS-9960 sensor in AOSP.
Please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it.

Open the config file `bcm2711_defconfig` under the kernel path `kernel/arpi/arch/arm64/configs` and change the config value `CONFIG_I2C_CHARDEV=y`.
This will enable the `dev/i2c`.